# how to hide activated menu link from wp-admin dashboard

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

get list of activate plugin in wordpress and remove plugin link from admin menu
.i want to remove activate plugin link from admin sidebar. how can this be done ?.
how to hide activate menu link from wp-admin dashboard

Comment: Can you post a screenshot  of what you want to remove ?

Comment: when we install and activate plugin in wp  like contact form etc it link appears in admin sidebar as contact  . like this all plugin  link appears i want to hide it

Comment: yes but solutiion is not available